# How map DTO to Entity without the @GenerateValue field in JPA

Tags: jpa, mapping, entity, dto

I have a DTO class with some field and i'm trying to map DTO in Entity class, in my entity class I have an id field (generate value), but not in DTO because i don't need to set a ID.

I have a DTO class :

```
@Data
public class ExampleDTO {

private String someField1
private String someField2

}
```

I have an entity class :

```
public class exampleEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String someField1
private String someField2
}
```

This is how I'm trying to map here :

```
ExampleJpaEntity exampleDTOtoExampleEntity(ExampleDTO exampleDTO) {
        return new ExampleJpaEntity(
                exampleDTO.getSomeField1,
                              exampleDTO.getSomeField2));
    }
```

But it dont work because it want to map also the field @id, the problem is i dont want because i
dont have an id my DTO class

How can I do for that ? because logically the @Id is generate by JPA

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you should add constructor in exampleEntity class.

```
    public class exampleEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String someField1;
private String someField2;

public exampleEntity(String someField1, String someField2) {
    this.someField1 = someField1;
    this.someField2 = someField2;
}
}
```